# Scrapping full Edgar into HTML fails due to condition has length > 1

Tags: html, r, nlp, bert-language-model, edgar

I always get the following error message despite in my view I am doing everything as in the R documentary.

```
> output <- getFilingsHTML(cik.no = 789019, 'ALL', 2018, quarter = c(1,2,3,4), useragent)
Downloading fillings. Please wait... 
  |=============================================================================================================================| 100%
Scrapping full EDGAR and converting to HTML...
  | 
                                                                                                                            |   0%Error in if (!grepl(pattern = "<xml>|<type>xml|<html>", filing.text, ignore.case = T)) { : 
  the condition has length > 1
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong here? I do not get it since the very same code worked one month ago.

Thank you very much

```
install.packages("edgar")  
install.packages("edgar")
##https://github.com/Gunratan/edgar 
##https://www.sec.gov/os/accessing-edgar-data
library(edgar)
useragent = "<YOUR PERSONAL EMAIL>" #please use your email address

output <- getFilingsHTML(cik.no = 789019, c('10-K','10-Q'),
                     2020, quarter = c(1, 2, 3), useragent)
```

Comment: Please provide the information required to reproduce the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I just got the same error and it seems to be a software problem. Function getFilingsHTML stores initial results in 'Master Indexes' as GZ files which are not converted to HTML and it seems to result in the error. I was able to do the conversion externally but not within EDGAR. So, I do not have a solution but I just sent a request to EDGAR authors for explanation and also gave them the link to your question. So, stay tuned.

Comment: The EDGAR authors fixed the bug and there is already an updated version 2.07 on CRAN. It works for me without  'useragent' this time.